# How to parse the numbers from the text and display it in textBox? c#

Tags: c#, text, numbers, tokenize

I have a string with the following text:

```
:0c4b7fcdffc38322555a9e35c22c9469:Nick:194176015020283762507:
```

How do I parse the final number? i.e.:

```
194176015020283762507
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) to separate the string by the colon (':') separators.  Then access the correct element.

```
var input = ":0c4b7fcdffc38322555a9e35c22c9469:Nick:194176015020283762507:";
var split = input.Split(':');
var final = split[3];
```

Note that by default, `Split()` keeps empty entries. You will have one at the beginning and end, because of the initial and ending colons.  You could also use:

```
var split = input.Split(new[] {':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var final = split[2];
```

which, as the option implies, removes empty entries from the array. So your number would be at index 2 instead of 3.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to up-vote any answers that helped, and accept the one that best answers your question.

Comment: There is no overload for `Split` method, which accepts char and split options.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = ":0c4b7fcdffc38322555a9e35c22c9469:Nick:194176015020283762507:";
string num = str.Split(':')[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var finalNumber = input.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Last()
```

This code will split your input string into strings, separated by `:` (empty strings are removed from start and end of sequence). And last string is returned, which is your finalNumber.